# Javascript e.pageX undefined

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

I'm starting to learn Javascript throu Youtube, and while I write this code down, it says that pageX is undefined. I could really use a help.  I'm working on a function that captures a positio of mouse on the screen. And don't please ask for HTML because it is only a form in it, nothing else.

Javascript :

```
 var mie = (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")?true:false;

if (!mie) {
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
    //document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
}

document.onmousemove = pozicijaMisa();
//document.onmousedown = misKliknut();
var misKliknut = 0;
var tipkaStisnuta = 0;
var misX = 0;
var misY = 0;

function pozicijaMisa(e) {
    if (!mie) {
        misX = e.pageX;
        misY = e.pageY;
    } else {
        misX  =event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
        misY  =event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
    }
    document.forma.misx.value = misX;
    document.forma.misy.value = misY;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend something like this instead of that outdated YouTube video: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I would find a different tutorial since they are teaching outdated practices

Your problem is:

```
document.onmousemove = pozicijaMisa();
```

should be an assignment, not calling it and assigning what it returns to the event handler.

```
document.onmousemove = pozicijaMisa;
```

Comment: This removed error from e.pageX part, but now pops out on this line of code :
document.forma.misx.value = misX; saying : java2.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

Comment: What is the error? And do you have a form with that input?

Comment: Sorry, found the problem, I misspelled my form name ;S Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2):

You're doing client detection via `navigator`, which is brittle.

It will serve you better to do feature detection in Javascript instead of client detection. Instead of seeing if you're using IE, see if `pageX` exists (especially because newer versions of IE don't use pageX).

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousePosition);
function mousePosition(e) {
  var x = e['pageX'] || e.clientX;
  var y = e['pageY'] || e.clientY;
}
```